# How use keyboard only to open VMware Clarity <clr-dropdown> component?

Tags: vmware-clarity

We are using the VMware Clarity component .  I am trying to get keyboard accessibility working so that the dropdown menu displays.  How can I do this?

I added tabindex="0" to the top  element and am successful tabbing to the "Settings" icon so that it has focus.  However, I am unable to figure out how to open the dropdown menu with any keyboard keys.  I tried adding tabindex="0" to  and/or  within the , but no luck opening the dropdown with any of the keys: Enter, Space, Down Arrow, Up Arrow.

```
<div id="header-action-settings" tabindex="0" title="Settings"
   class="nav-link nav-icon">
    <clr-dropdown [clrCloseMenuOnItemClick]="true">
        <button tabindex="0" clrDropdownTrigger aria-haspopup="true">
            <clr-icon size="18" shape="dell-settings-gear"></clr-icon>
            <clr-icon shape="play right" *ngIf="settingsMenuExpanded"></clr-icon>
            <clr-icon shape="play top"*ngIf="!settingsMenuExpanded"></clr-icon>
        </button>
        <ng-template [(clrIfOpen)]="settingsMenuExpanded">
            <clr-dropdown-menu clrPosition="bottom-right">
                <label class="dropdown-header">
                    <div class="float-xs-left">System</div>
                    <div class="float-xs-right">
                        <clr-icon shape="play left" class="text-gray"></clr-icon>
                    </div>
                </label>
                <button tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" class="settings-system-link" type="button" (click)="showSystem()" clrDropdownItem>
                    <span tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" class="pl-3">System</span>
                </button>
            </clr-dropdown-menu>
        </ng-template>
    </clr-dropdown>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a pending PR that will address this issue. Please subscribe and follow here: https://github.com/vmware/clarity/pull/3283

Comment: Great!  This PR points to another one too:  https://github.com/vmware/clarity/pull/3252

Comment: Correct. The original author wasn’t able to finish getting the PR merged in and we had to take it over. There are only a few minor changes to it and it’s currently being worked on.

Comment: We are currently using 0.11.29 and it is going to be difficult to move to the latest version to get this fix.  Do you know of another way to capture the <enter> key click and open the <clr-dropdown> menu?

Comment: If you post a stackblitz with what you have tried so far I’ll be happy to take a look at it.